# iOS multiline text with VFL Constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, screen-rotation

I want to display a switch button and a text on the same line. (and a list of those)
But when the text is too long, it doesn't spread on 2 lines right away, it first takes over the switch. Then goes on 2 lines if even longer. I, of course, cannot manage the length this string will be.

My constraint right now is very basic : `@"H:|-[switchBtn%d]-[nameL%d]-|"`

And the top view is simply `@"H:|-[containerView]-|"`

I tried using a size that was about 70% of the screen width with the metrics, but when I'm rotating the screen, I can't make it update this value correctly. It will not resize when changing screen orientation. I've tried updating the metrics dictionary, and re-attaching the constraints/updating them. No can do.

Is there something I'm missing somewhere?
Is it a bad idea to change the metric dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Content Compression Resistance Priority on the switch button to a higher value than the text's? See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622526-setcontentcompressionresistancep?language=objc

Comment: I will try this and close if I can make it work. Thank you !

Comment: Working when I lower the priority on the text (but not if I put the switch on a higher value).
Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[nameL setContentCompressionResistancePriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Did the trick. Thanks Guy.